# C comparing two characters

Tags: c

I am trying to compare two characters using `strcmp`:

```
const char comm[sizeof(argv[4])];
strcpy(comm,argv[4]);
if(strcmp(']', comm[strlen(comm)-1]) != 0)
    { code }
```

Where `argv[4]` is a string like: "potato".

Gives me "Passing argument 2 of strcmp makes pointer from integer without a cast"

Comment: @chux, Lets not scare the beginner. :p

Comment: `const char comm[sizeof(argv[4])];` should be `char comm[strlen(argv[4])];`.

Comment: @mch +1 for your comment but also the string terminator needs `+1` --> `char comm[strlen(argv[4])+1];`

Answer (score 2):

Characters should be compared like this

```
if (']' == comm[strlen(comm)-1])
```

PS: [Yoda conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions) rules. :)

---

`strcmp()` is for strings.